# Flutter Unreal Colors

Tags: flutter, xcode, visual-studio, dart, ios-simulator

The colors come out very different from what I did in the design program. The color codes are the same but very different. The problem is with the theme color.

```
//App Theme Colors  
  static const Color appThemeColor = Color(0xFF5FCAC2);
  
//Orange Button Color
  static const Color chip1 = Color(0xFFFFB44D);
```

[image]

Comment: The same issue applies to the theme color.

Comment: Is that button active or disabled?  Disabled buttons are greyed.

Comment: the button is active, only the color is displayed differently

Comment: It looks the proper color to be disabled.  Are you sure you have a non-null onTap: ?